# Comparing dates in Oracle using the decode function

Tags: sql, oracle, date, decode, date-arithmetic

I need to compare two dates using the Oracle decode function to see if one is `less than or equal` to the other.

I found this article - http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php

Which states (at the bottom) that the below decode function will return date2 if date1 > date2 :

```
decode((date1 - date2) - abs(date1 - date2), 0, date2, date1)
```

Would this not return date2 if date1 >= date2 ?

Or is it just if date1 > date2?

Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That function will return date2 if date2 <= date1.  Plugging in the values and translating to pseudo-code, you get `if 0 - 0 = 0 then date2 else date1` where both dates are the same.

---

A better solution, if you're using 8i or later is to use `case`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN date1 >= date2 THEN date2 ELSE date1 END FROM Your_Table;
```

Since `case` allows inequality operators, it's much more readable.

---

Or, if you want to be more succinct, you could use the function that's designed to return the lower of n values:

```
SELECT LEAST(date1, date2) FROM Your_Table;
```

(There is also a `GREATEST` function, which does the opposite.)

Answer (score 7):

@Allan has already given you the best solution to me, but if you insist on using `decode` function, you can process the result of `sign` function instead.

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/sign.php

`sign(a)` returns `-1` if `a < 0`, `0` if `a = 0` and `1` if `a > 0`. Thus, the following logic

```
if date1 >= date2 then
    return date1;
else
    return date2;
end if;
```

could be rewritten using `decode` in the following way:

```
select decode(sign(date2-date1), 
              -1 /*this means date 1 > date 2*/, date1 /* return date1*/, 
               0 /*dates are equal */,           date1 /* again, return date1*/,
               /*in any other case, which is date2 > date1, return date2*/ date2) 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [`months_between`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_x_monitor004.htm) function. It will calculate the number of months between two dates, as a decimal number.

```
select months_between(sysdate+30, sysdate ) from dual;
select months_between(sysdate+15, sysdate ) from dual;
```

In this example, the first paramater is greater than the second so it will return 1. The second line returns ~0.48 (when executed at about 11:30 AM on 2010-09-01) To get the actual date values:

```
select case when months_between(sysdate+30, sysdate ) > 0 then sysdate+30 else sysdate end from dual;
```

In general:

```
case when months_between(dateA, dateB ) > 0 then dateA else dateB
```

**Update:**

After some experimentation, it seems the finest granularity of this function is Day.

```
select months_between(to_date('2010-10-16 23:59:59', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                       to_date('2010-10-16 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
from dual;
```

...will return 0

but

```
select months_between(to_date('2010-10-17 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),
                       to_date('2010-10-16 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
from dual;
```

will return 0.032258064516129.

Some other interesting date difference/compare techniques here: http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_get_the_time_difference_between_two_date_columns

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to check by date - that is, every time in 1/1 is less than 1/2, and every on 1/1 is equal to every other time on 1/1, even if the Oracle DATE is greater - then you want to compare as follows:

TRUNC(DATE1) <= TRUNC(DATE2)

I don't see this in the other answers, it is so basic it makes me wonder if I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I see now that you explicitly said you wanted DECODE.  I would use CASE for a question like this where you're evaluating a boolean condition.  Regardless, don't forget to cut off the minutes when you're comparing dates, unless you want the comparison to the maximum precision.

Comment: Excellent point, I accounted for that already as I work with dates quite often but it's a good one to mention if others end up looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

This is better:

```
decode(sign(trunc(sysdate) - (trunc(sysdate))), 1, 1, -1, -1, 0 , 0)

1: date 1 > date 2
0: date 1 = date 2
-1: date 1 < date 2
```

Answer (score 0):

will return date2 when date1 >= date2